# How to add active class for current item and ancestor in new WooCommerce Product Categories List Block widget?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a Product Categories List Block to list all product categories in sidebar in shop and category pages (like filters). I am listing categories in my site by using a wordpress Widget. Categories are shown but there is no active class for current category or ancestor category. How to make it that if user is on current category, the li item will get current-cat class and ancestor current-ancestor class?

[HTML STRUCTURE OF WIDGET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOCC4.png)

Answer (score 4):

I needed to solve this myself, so here is my current solution.

Since there is currently no filter available for the default WooCommerce blocks, I solved it using [PHP's DOMDocument parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) while rendering the block.

You can add a filter to `render_block` to catch the html for the specific block, in this case the block name is `woocommerce/product-categories`. By adding checks for non-admin & non-json requests we make sure the changes only happen on the front-end output.

If you add the code below to your theme's `functions.php`, a class `current-category-item` is added to the list item that matches the current url.

```
function custom_render_block_wc_product_categories(string $block_content, array $block): string
{
    if(
        $block['blockName'] !== 'woocommerce/product-categories'
        || is_admin()
        || wp_is_json_request()
    ) {
        return $block_content;
    }

    $html = '';

    global $wp;
    $current_slug = trim($wp->request,'/');

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($block_content);
    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    if( $elements['length'] ){
        foreach ($elements as $node){
            $href = parse_url($node->getAttribute('href'));
            $path = trim($href['path'], '/');

            if( $path === $current_slug ){
                $class = $node->parentNode->getAttribute('class');
                $class .= ' current-category-item';
                $node->parentNode->setAttribute('class', $class);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $html .= "<div class='block-outer-wrapper'>";
    $html .= "<header><h4>" . __('Categories','woocommerce') . "</h4></header>";
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML();
    $html .= "</div>";

    return $html;
}
add_filter('render_block', 'custom_render_block_wc_product_categories', 10, 2);
```

I also added a header to the block, but these lines are optional as long as you `return $dom->saveHTML()` after your changes.

Comment: Nice work - you deserved credit for the answer! It will be interesting to see when/if filters are added, but in the meantime...

Comment: Just wanted to say Thank You! for providing a solution for a problem that shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works very well, but I edited this line

```
> $dom->loadHTML($block_content);
```

to

```
> $dom->loadHTML( '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
> charset=utf-8">' . $block_content);
```

my site is in Cyrillic and it breaks the encoding